# Find smallest value of $m$ such that $256$ divides $g(n)$ for $ g(n)= (n)(n+1)\cdots(n+m)$ for all n

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This is my solution so far:
256 divides g(n) means
\begin{equation}                                
g(n)= p*256\\      
n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3).....(n+m)= p*256\\     (n+m)= \frac{p*256}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3).....(n+m-1)}\\
\end{equation}
I have no clue in what direction to go to find the m from here or even if this is the method I should follow

Comment: Assuming that $n$ is a positive integer, and $256|g(n)$ for all $n$, it will be useful to observe that $256=2^8$.

Comment: First find the value of $m$ for $n=1$?  Then note, or prove, that $g(1)$ divides $g(n)$.

Comment: If you mean for all $n$ you should say so.  If $n$ is a multiple of $256$ then $m =0$ is the smallest.

Comment: Consder if $n$ is odd then $n+1$, $n+3$, $n+5$, .... $n + 9$ are all even.  So $2|n+1$ and $2|n_3$ etc.  so $2^8 |(n+1)(n+3), ..... (n+9)$ and $2^8 =256$. So $m=9$ works.  Now make that more efficient.

Comment: Ooops.... I mean $2^8|(n+1) (n+3)....... (n+17)$ so $m=17$ works.  But we can make that more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick is to realize that given any two consecutive numbers $a, a+1$ one of them is even one of them is odd. So $2|a(a+1)$.  Always.

ANd if you have $a, a+1, a+2, a+3,........, a+2k$ then $k$ of those numbers will be even (and $k$ of them will be odd).  So as $2^k|a(a+1)(a+2).....(a+2k)$.

And as $256 = 2^8$ we will always have $2^8|n(n+1)(n+2)......(n+16)$.

But we can do better.

Suppose we have an even number $2k$ and the next even number is $2k + 2$.  One of those is divisible by $4$ and then other isn't.  Consider if $k=2m$ is even then $2k = 2(2m) =4m$ is divisible by $4$ and $2k+2 = 4m + 2= 4(m + \frac 12)$ is not.  And if $k=2m+1$ is odd, then the exact opposite happens:  $2k = 2(2m+1)=4m+2$ is not divisible by $4$ but $2k + 2 = 2(2m+1) +2 = 4m + 4 = 4(m+1)$ is.

So if you have $n,n+1, n+2,n+3$ two of those numbers are even, And one of the even numbers is divisible by $4$ and the other is only divisible by $2$.  But one is divisible by $2$ and another by $4$ so $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ will have one component divisible by $2$ and another by $4$ so $8$ will divide $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.

And that means that $8|n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ and $8|(n+4)(n+5)(n+6)(n+7)$ so $8\cdot 8 =64$ will divide $n(n+1).....(n+7)$.

But we can do better.  If $4|k$ then $4|k+4$ but one of them is divisible not just by $4$ but by $8$.  And the other isn't.  The reason is the same.  If $k = 4m$ and if $m=2j$ is even then $k=4m=8j$.  And $k+4 = 8j+4$ is not divisible by $8$.  And if $m=2j+1$ is odd then $k = 4(2j+1)=8j+4$ is not divisible by $8$ but $k+4 = 4(2j+1)+4 = 8j +8=8(j+1)$ is.

So that means one of the cluster of $4$ consectutive terms has $2$ even terms and one of them is divisible by $4$, and the other cluster of $4$ consecutive terms has $2$ even terms and one of them is divisible by $8$.  So $8$ will divide one of the clusters, and $16$ will divide the other.

So $8\cdot 16 = 128$ will divide $n(n+1).....(n+7)$.

To assure that $256 = 2\cdot 128$ will divide a series of consectutive terms we need just one more even number.

So if we tag on $(n+8)(n+9)$ then $n,n+1,.....,n+9$ well have at $5$ even numbers. And least two of them are divisible by $4$.  And at least one will by divisible by $8$.  So $8\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2= 256$ will divide $n(n+1) ..... (n+9)$.

We can test this wit $1......$

$256$ does not divide $1$. so $m > 0$.

$256$ does not divide $1\cdot 2 = 2$ (but $2$ does).  So $m > 1$.

$256$ does not divide $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4=24$ (but $8$ does).. So $m > 3$.

$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8$ is divisible by $2\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 8=128$ but not by $256$.

$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9$ is divisible by $128$ but not $256$ but

$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9\cdot 10$  is divisible by $256$ and we will need ten terms in the worst case, and will never need more than ten.

So $m =9$

Answer (score 3):

Using mine and Brian's idea (mostly Brian's), we only need to check for what values of $m$, $g(1) = (m+1)!$ is divisible by $256 = 2^8$.

In $2 \times 4 \times 6 \times 8$, the power of $2$ in the prime factorization is $2^1\times 2^2\times2^1\times 2^3=2^7$. This means we need one more even number, i.e. $10$. Therefore $256\mid 10!$, and $m=9$.

To show that claim that $g(1)\mid g(n)$, notice that

$$\frac {g(n)} {g(1)} = \frac {(n+m)!}{(n-1)!}\cdot\frac 1 {(m+1)!}=\binom{n+m}{m+1}$$

and binomial coefficients are always integers.

Comment: That's all there is to it (binomial coefficients FTW)! Given a natural number $m$ this eventually leads to a characterization of the set $I(m)$ of polynomials $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(n)$ is divisible by $m$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. Predicted integer multiples of polynomials of the form $f_j(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-j+1)$ generate $I(m)$ as an ideal.